# extract coefficient and significance level in GARCH model in stata

Tags: loops, coefficients, arch

I use STATA to do EGARCH-M model on panel data. id=478, time=1990-2014.

here is my code:

```
forvalues i=1 (1) 478 {
`arch ut rmrf if id==`i', arch(1) garch(1) archmexp(sqrt(X)) distribution(t)
 replace beta=_b[_sigma2] if id==`i'
 }
```

`

the coefficient code doesn't work. and I have no idea how to get significance level, i.e. z-statistic and p-value

finally, it would be wonderful that, STATA can help me to summarize the number of beta with significant positive; significant negative; insignificant positive; insignificant negative.

I am really grateful if someone could help me to figure out this code!

Many thanks!